# head isn't included in syntax/sh.vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash, shell

`head` is a common Unix/Linux executable, but it's not listed in the shell syntax highlighting configuration.

In contrast, many common executables are. Specifically, its counterpart, `tail`, *is* listed. As are some not uncommon, but not fundamental executables like `less` and `rpm`.

It's also interesting that the lists differ between the `syn keyword` `bashStatement`, `kshStatement` and `shStatement` sections in the `Misc` "fold" for executables even when they are independent from the shell. For example, `cat` is only listed in the ksh section.

What is the reason `head` is omitted? Why are there these other discrepancies?

Comment: Personally I find the entire list a bit insane (both the bash and ksh ones), but it's been the case for at least 15 years: https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/41b884b27387cd4c0ba1d039ea3bb2b7beac21c2/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L276

Comment: I would be inclined to close this question as primarily opinion based: The fact is that this syntax file has been like this for 15 years and I don't see how someone could answer why Braam decided to keep these items and not some other. However @Dennis if you really are not satisfied with this file you can still open a PR maybe Braam will accept it or at least give a good reason for why he choose not to include `head`.

Comment: I think these two comments come close to qualifying as an answer. As would a hypothetical "here's a third-party file that fixes all-the-things".

Comment: I suppose one could just ask the syntax/sh.vim maintainer...not Braam but the "vim famous" [Dr. Chip](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_SH). BTW, our very own @ChristianBrabandt maintains `syntax/zsh.vim` and `indent/sh.vim`...being involved with those he might run in the same social circles as doc chip or otherwise have gained some insight into the matter. :)

Comment: "Bug" [fixed](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10639#issuecomment-1170511655).